# “Welcome to emergency mode!” device descriptor read/64, error -110

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu

So I just got this error and I think I may know why, but am not sure how to go about fixing it exactly (don't want to do a clean install if at all possible).

I am pretty sure I deleted something I shouldn't have (via "apt-get purge")-- the package ntfs-3g. If this is the cause, is it possible to reinstall the package somehow?

I am running dual boot Windows 10 and Lubuntu 16.x.

Comment: I really dont know whats the issue you talk about, but you can install anything you "purged" with `sudo apt-get install package-name`

Comment: Emergency mode forces me into the root command line and will not allow me to fun the 'apt-get install ..' without throwing errors:

"""
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakety-updates/main amd64 ntfs-3g amd64 1:2016.2.22AR.1-3ubuntu0.1
     Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'